# What are these enclosed box characters?

Tags: apl

When you enclose something it's in this little box. Sometimes there are these symbols making up the box. Arrows, broken lines, tildes, epsilons. What do they mean

Comment: You may want to state which version of APL you're using and include an example input and output.

Comment: Dyalog is my APL

Answer (score 8):

If you turn boxing on with `-style=max` (or use `]Display`) you will see these characters in the borders of the boxes. E.g. with `]box on -style=max`:

```
      1 3⍴'123' ⍬ ('1'2)
┌→────────────────┐
↓ ┌→──┐ ┌⊖┐ ┌→──┐ │
│ │123│ │0│ │1 2│ │
│ └───┘ └~┘ └+──┘ │
└∊────────────────┘
```

The `→`s mean that there is a trailing axis. The `↓` means that there is an additional axis. So the outer shape is a matrix. Its `∊` means that it is nested.

The smooth bottom border of `123` means it is a character (not numeric) vector (indicated by the single axis; `→`).

The `~` means numeric array, and it has a single zero-length axis indicated by `⊖`. (Also the prototype is a single `0`).

The `+` means mixed type (here: character and numeric). Note that this vector is *not* nested.

In summary, the symbols are `∊` for nested, `~` for numeric, `─` for character, `#` for namespace, `∇` for object representation, and `+` for Mixed. The full documentation can be obtained with `]???box`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/@v8ahvql/wo941mnoaqXmJSTmpwY4@IY@6FgPFnSPVixNzStQ1////H2tvb5@UXwEA)